# How and when to use preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript

From this **[tutorial](http://blog.nmsdvid.com/when-to-use-return-false-and-when-preventdefault/)**, it is said:

> `preventDefault();` does one thing: It stops the browsers default
>   behaviour.

I searched online for the examples of `preventDefault()`, I can only see in two situations (link, form) we use `preventDefault()`: Prevent a submit button from submitting a form and prevent a link from following the URL.

So, my question is:

1. In what other situations can we use `preventDefault()`?
2. How could I find out all the browsers default behaviour? e.g. if I click a button, what is the browsers default behaviour?

Comment: https://javascript.info/default-browser-action  and https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#common-event-behaviors

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1. In what other situation can we use preventDefault()?**

Actually any type of event, you can stop its default behavior with the `preventDefault();`
So not only submit buttons, but keypresses, scrolling events, you name it and you can prevent it from happening. Or if you'd like add your own logic to the default behavior, think of logging an event or anything of your choice.

**2. How could I find out all the browsers default behaviour? e.g. if I click a button, what is the browsers default behaviour?**

What do you mean with this? Mostly the default behavior is kind of implied. When you click a button, the onclick event fires. When you click the submit button, the form is submitted. When the windows scrolls, the onscroll event fires.

Answer (score 3):

Every item in the DOM has some 'default behaviour'. This is for every browser about the same (some exceptions excluded). If you want your own logic to be executed instead of the default behavior, you can use the preventDefault() function. The same goes for the stopPropagation() function which stopt events from bubbling up the event tree if you just want your own logic being executed and nothing else from there on.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) In what else situation we can use `preventDefault()`?

Various form fields update their state in response to certain events, such as a checkbox when you click it. If you `preventDefault` on `click`, the checkbox reverts to its earlier checked state. There are lots of behaviors — when keys are pressed, when the window is scrolled, when an element is focussed...

> 2) How could I find out all the browsers default behaviour? e.g. if I click a button, what is the browsers default behaviour?

[The specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) lists the "activation behavior" of each element. Compare the activation behavior described for [`a` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) to that described for [`input[type=checkbox]`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#checkbox-state-%28type=checkbox%29), for instance. (The "pre-click activation steps" are interesting, too.)

Comment: The link just points to the entire specification doc. Here is the section that specifies common event actions.  These are the actions that preventDefault() would "prevent".  It is different for each element. [w3org specs: common event behaviours](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#common-event-behaviors)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in every type of event, for example:

```
element.onclick = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event

    if (event.preventDefault) { // W3C variant
        event.preventDefault()
    } else { // IE < 9 variant. It doesn't work in older version of IE
        event.returnValue = false
    }
}
```

What's the difference between `returning false` or using `event.preventDefault`?

1. return false. Stops the default browser action AND **finish** the handling.
2. event.preventDefault. Stops the default browser action BUT **doesn't finish** the handling

This is a useful [link](http://javascript.info/tutorial/default-browser-actio) that explains it deeply.